# Rails javascript not firing despite ready page:load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I'm using stripe with rails and the ajax calls seem to work fine whenever I refresh the page.  I believe this is an issue with turbolinks, the 'ready page:load' doesn't work as I expected.

Here's the form for the card:

```
<%= form_tag subscribers_path, id:'subscriber_form' do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Add Card</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :"Card Number" %>
        <%= text_field_tag nil, nil, "data-stripe":"number", size:"20" %>
      </div>


      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :"Expiration Date" %>
        <%= text_field_tag nil, nil, "data-stripe":"exp_month", size:"2" %>/
        <%= text_field_tag nil, nil, "data-stripe":"exp_year", size:"2" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :"CVC" %>
        <%= text_field_tag nil, nil, "data-stripe":"cvc", size:"4" %>
      </div>



    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <%= submit_tag "Add card", class:"btn btn-primary submit", id:"card_submit_button" %>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
<% end %>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () { 


  $('#subscriber_form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    console.log($form);
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $form.find('.submit').val('loading...');

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
  });

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#subscriber_form');

    if (response.error) {
      $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
      $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      $form.find('.submit').val('submit');
    } else {
      $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

      var dataSet = $form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        data: dataSet,
        dataType: "script",
        complete: function(){
          $form.get(0).reset();
          console.log(response);
          $('#card_select input:last').prop("checked", "checked");


          $('#cardModal').modal('hide')

          $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false);
          $form.find('.submit').val('Add card');

        },
        error: function(exception){console.log("exception" + exception);}
      });
    }
  };


});
```

The script still doesn't work when I follow a link to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no .on('ready') so maybe you should try an approach similar to this:

`var stripe;`

`stripe = function() {...};`

`$(document).ready(stripe);`

`$(document).on('page:load', stripe);`

Comment: I might be using it wrong but I'm basing it on the "events" section of this document https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic

Comment: If you check the jQuery section about the ready method, you'll see the .on('ready') has a weird behaviour and has been deprecated since version 1.8